# Submit Form when value is entered on LabelFor

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a webapp which receives text when a barcode is scanned and submit it, which would be the same as submitting it when writing any letter in the textbox with a keyboard. I've tried with this code, but it submit it when the focus is changed from the textbox, not when the value is entered:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Escaneado</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Texto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Texto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Texto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cargar escaneados", "LoadScans")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Texto').change(function () {
                $('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I've tried using a `.trigger` in the script, looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Texto').change(function () {
                $('form').submit();
            });
            $('#Texto').trigger("change");
        });
</script>
```

which submits, but when the page reloads after submitting, it enters in an infinite loop of submitting

Comment: Checkout the `OnInput` or `OnKeyDown` events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this script, the info is submitted and it doesn't loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Texto').on('input', function () {
                $('form').submit();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Change()`  event fires when the user types into the input and then loses focus. you will need to trigger the event when you pass that data, something like [`.trigger("change")`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I changed it to this, which works and submit  `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Texto').change(function () {
                $('form').submit();
            });
            $('#Texto').trigger("change");
        });

    </script>`  
But after submitting, when the page realods it submit again without entering any character, starting an infinite loop